# In EDMX SaveChanges()

Tags: linq, entity-framework, wcf

If i am updating with same records which are existing in **EDMX** and i want to return if update successful then return 1.
But when i am not changing any values and update **EDMX** it is returning 0.
How to get 1 for if same records are exist and no changes made into **EDMX**.

My requirement is,I am returning basically **Row Changes** that i know about that any changes are made or not.Is there predefined method that i returned 1 for if there is no exception occurred.

Answer (score 0):

use try and catch if exception return 0 else return 1.

```
try
{
    context.SaveChanges();
    return 1;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //log exception here.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But i want in same i.e in try block.

Comment: @user3169885 Do you want all return statement in try? why any specific reason?